# How do I get the Owner field to be populated in Azure DevOps when running tests from SpecFlow?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, specflow, vstest

I have a suite of automation test using selenium that run using SpecFlow. I run the tests through a VSTest task in Azure DevOps Pipelines and I want to populate the Owner field.

[image: Azure DevOps Test results]

I checked SpecFlow documentation and on page 119 (https://docs.specflow.org/_/downloads/specflow/en/latest/pdf/) it describes adding an owner using the @ symbol

[image: SpecFlow Documentation]

However I tried adding this tag to both the scenarios and the features and the owner always shows up as "unspecified". Can someone help here? I would also be happy to figure out how to populate the "Tags" field but I spoke with Microsoft and they don't think that will be possible.

SpecFlow .feature file test 1

```
@Owner:SearchRecent
Feature: RecentSearch

    @SmokeTest
    Scenario: RecentSearch_UserCanOptIn
        When I call POST endpoint
        Then I get 200 response
```

SpecFlow .feature file test 2

```
Feature: RecentSearch

    @SmokeTest
    @Owner:SearchRecent
    Scenario: RecentSearch_UserCanOptIn
        When I call POST endpoint
        Then I get 200 response
```

task in Yaml file

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\APITests.dll      
      !**\obj\**
      !**\bin\**\ref\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=${{ parameters.testTags }}'
    uiTests: true
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
    runSettingsFile: '<insert-path>/${{ parameters.environment }}.runsettings'
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
    collectDumpOn: 'always'
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunFailedThreshold: '70'
    rerunMaxAttempts: '3'
```

Then when i run the pipeline I see the test result as passed. but it shows the owner as "not available"

[image: RecentSearch_UserCanOptIn Result]

Comment: We do not have enough information to provide you an answer. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I updated. is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is perfect!

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: Seems like MSTest, can you please help with a solution for this. I am also looking for adding Owner is Azure DevOps.

Comment: The question has good details now i think. Do we have solution @GregBurghardt ?

Comment: Do you see the `[Owner]` attribute in the *.feature.cs files generated when building the project locally and on the build server?